# Single input multiple choice UI

Tags: usability, website-design, gui-design

I am working on small project(web page) where a user can have two options to get results. But only one can be used at a time.
Being a noob with UI and stuff, I would like to know how to work on such scenarios.

To get user details(internal tool), a user can enter either email address or phone number. Only 1 among the two at a time. The details will then be populated down.
It won't redirect anywhere and user can get details of user without reloading page or navigating elsewhere.

I was thinking of something like below.
[image]
How can I improve the same or any references you can share?

Answer (score 3):

Is it necessary to have two fields knowing that each of the two options has different contents?

If the user inserts an `@` they will have placed an email. On the contrary, if they type `+numbers`, a telephone.

[image]

<sub>*[Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/drewsher/pen/jOqvLya)*</sub>

Comment: This one seems interesting, Also can you suggest something where both options are text like some alphabetical id and name?

Comment: If you know some javascript for sure you will have no problem finding the solution by modifying the attached codepen script.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for the demo with code.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps use a radio button, letting the user know he has a choice of either or but not both, and an input that changes according to the users choice.
if you have previous data to know which of the two will be used more, have that choice selected by default.

[image]

Comment: Why couldn't I think of this simple approach earlier? It's so simple!

Answer (score 0):

Similar to mayag's suggestion, we solved a related question as follows:

[image]

This went through multiple discussions and this version was the one where most agreed. This part is in a checkout process and this specific field is about tax identification. In brackets the first one says "(preferred)" and second one "(alternative)".